# Get element from array from html-file

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm using meteor (version 1.8) with blaze.js and mongodb.

I'm trying to use an array-element which looks like this on the html file:

```
{{#each name in chatMeta.lastWhisp}}
 <div class="WhisperCharacter">
  {{name}}  
 </div>
{{/each}}
```

The corresponding helper for this query looks like this:

```
chatMeta() {
return ChatMeta.findOne({});
},
```

The collection that gets queried has an array "lastWhisp"

```
"lastWhisp": ["StringA", "StringB"]
```

I'm trying to get the information of {{name}} with an event handler:

```
  'click .WhisperCharacter'(event, template) {
    alert(this.name); //<- Wrong
  },
```

Normally, I'm able to retrieve the data with `this.x` on the `{{each}}` handlebar, but that only seems to work if I query whole documents each, not with an array inside one single document.

I tried a lot of funky stuff like `this.lastWhisp.name` etc. basically guessing. I can't get behind what it needs to retrieve the information of that `{{each}}` handlebar. Could someone help me out with how it works in this case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event itself has no information on the `name`, because it represents only that you have clicked a DOM element.

To transport this value, you may use a `data-*` [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes):

```html
{{#each name in chatMeta.lastWhisp}}
 <div class="WhisperCharacter" data-name="{{name}}">
  {{name}}  
 </div>
{{/each}}
```

you can then easily read the data attribute from the event using the builtin [jQuery `.data` method](https://api.jquery.com/data/) on the event target:

```js
'click .WhisperCharacter'(event, template) {
  const $target = template.$(event.currentTarget)
  const name = $target.data('name')
  alert(name)
},
```